# How ignite lock works

Tags: java, ignite

I have two threads one is taking lock and other is releasing lock on same key. But it is failing and throwing `IllegalStateException`.

How to fix the issue in Ignite?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This behavior seems to be correct. The semantics of `Lock` itself works that way. You should follow the pattern:

```java
    Lock l = ...;
    l.lock();
    try {
        // access the resource protected by this lock
    } finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
```

I suppose you're looking for a way to do some inter-Thread notification. My bet is that you can try [IgniteCountDownLatch](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/countdownlatch). It works mostly like the regular [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: can we use IgniteLock or semaphore

Comment: It depends on your case, give me more details about what do you want to achieve.

Comment: There is one thread which is taking lock and another thread releasing lock on same key. I want to use IgniteLock

Comment: I have custom lock and and unlock api. In lock I want to take lock on given key from ignite cache and in unlock,I want release lock which is acquired in lock() api

Comment: I have tried to to take lock  from ignite cache also and IgniteLock from ignite instance also. both fails

Comment: alos Not able understand how to use IgniteCountDownLactch between custom lock and unlock api

Comment: Also IgniteCache have lock api but not unlock

Comment: I used semaphore and ignite.semaphore(key,1,true,create) //Create flag depends on lock/unlcok. My code stucks at ignite.semaphore(key,1,true,create)  for some use case in lock and for some in unlock